# python get a list of expressions

Tags: python, list

I have this in my config (ini) file:

```
result = "name\tage\tdob"
```

This is what I want as my final output (as a list) - to write this to an output file where the real values will be written as a single line:

```
[str(row["name"]).strip(), str(row["age"]).strip(), str(row["dob"]).strip()]
```

My python reads 'result' from config file as a string and I do some manupulation to get to something close to what I need. I am stuck after that. This is what I did:

```
list1 = result.decode('string_escape').split()
list2 = map(lambda x: x.replace('\"', ''), list1)
list3 = map(lambda x: 'str(row[' + '"'  + x + '"' + ']).strip()', list2);
print list3
```

And it prints list3 as:

```
['str(row["name"]).strip()', 'str(row["age"]).strip()', 'str(row["dob"]).strip()']
```

Now, if you notice, the elements of list3 are strings...which I don't want. How do I ensure that elements of the list are just python expressions...? I tried to do replace("'", ""), but it did not help.

Any suggestion is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
list3 = map(lambda x: str(row[x]).strip(), list2);
```

Note that, of course, you won’t see `str(row["name"]).strip()` in the output but rather whatever value that evaluates to.